# Twilio Android Client:Wait For a incoming call and then navigate to activity which will receive the call

Tags: android, twilio

I am developing an twilio android client which will wait for an incoming call and naviagte to another activity to accept and answer the call.

```
phone = BasicPhone.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
phone.setuuid(client_name);
phone.setListeners(this, this, this);
phone.login();
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BasicPhoneActivity.class); 


if (inDevice != null && inConnection != null) {
      intent.removeExtra(Device.EXTRA_DEVICE);
      intent.removeExtra(Device.EXTRA_CONNECTION);
      startActivity(intent);
     }
```

Can this be acheived ? I am getting null pointer exception with pendingIncomingConnection.setConnectionListener(this);

More info:

When the user launches the app he is currently in Activity "X" and then if there is an incoming call he should be autmatically sent to  Activity "Y".

What do I code in Activity X to wait for the incoming call (Via Twilio).

Please help!

Comment: did n't get your question. Do you want to attend the call as the call comes in the phone?

Comment: You got an NPE, then there must be an entry in the logcat. Post your stacktrace.

Comment: When the user launches the app he is currently in Activity "X" and then if there is an incoming call he should be autmatically sent to Activity "Y".